# How to make flexible buttons without using Auto resize

Tags: css

I'm new in CSS, I have buttons, with text and value on top, values are variable, sometimes big and some times small, I want my button to be same in the size but flexible against the size of the values, I have provided a demo also to clarify my problem better:

```css
.btnsForCrew-Common {
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: xx-small;
  width: 15%;
}

.CrewPrsntButtonsIdle {
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightgreen 15%, white 10%);
}

.FontsForCrewPresents {
  font-size: 40px
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnIdle" class="btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">ERROR</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 254</span>    
</button>

<button type="button" id="btnIdle1" class="btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">IDLE</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 100</span>    
</button>

<button type="button" id="btnIdle2" class="btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">WAITING To RUN</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 600000</span>    
</button>
```

The reason I do not want auto resize is; it makes the sizes different, I don't want that. Here is the demo:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sr8141f1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make them all them same size by wrapping them in an inline-block element and making them 100% width - then they will be as long as the largest:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
}
.wrapper > button {
  width:100%;
}

.btnsForCrew-Common {
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: xx-small;
}

.CrewPrsntButtonsIdle {
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightgreen 15%, white 10%);
}

.FontsForCrewPresents {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="btnIdle" class="btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">ERROR</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 254</span>    
</button>

  <button type="button" id="btnIdle1" class="btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">IDLE</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 100</span>    
</button>

  <button type="button" id="btnIdle2" class="btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">WAITING To RUN</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 600000</span>    
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing,this is what i wanted,and this wrapper > button tag does the flexibility ?i mean makes the button flexible?

Comment: That gives the button the width of the wrapper - the inline block on the wrapper is what does the flexibility

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.btnsForCrew-Common {
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: xx-small;
  width:50%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.CrewPrsntButtonsIdle {
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightgreen 20%, white 10%);
}

.FontsForCrewPresents {
  font-size: 40px
}


/*for auto resize
********
.btn {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
********
*/
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button type="button" id="btnIdle" class="btn btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">ERROR</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 254</span>    
</button>

  <button type="button" id="btnIdle1" class="btn btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">IDLE</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 100</span>    
</button>

  <button type="button" id="btnIdle2" class="btn btnsForCrew-Common CrewPrsntButtonsIdle"> 
  <span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;">WAITING To RUN</span>
  <br><br>
  <span class="FontsForCrewPresents"> 600000</span>    
</button>
</div>
```